# can any one tell me how to do this one n case/switch statement in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this data im getting from another table becauase i have 2 modes which is separately storing this id's to fetch that data only im doing like this
 i need to write this below code in switch/case statement

```
@pfold=""
     if(employeeproof.proof.id == 1 )
       @pfold = employeeproof.proof_value
  end
  @pfnew=""
      if(employeeproof.proof.id == 1 )
     @pfold = employeeproof.proof_value  
  end 
like this i have 20 conditions can any one tell me how to write this one in switch/case statement in rails
```

Comment: it is same as ruby man

Comment: i need in switch/case statement, that much lines of code is bad practices, i have written n if caonditions that is working perfectly

Comment: so you can search on google to write switch statement in ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it like :-

```
case employeeproof.proof.id
  when 1 then @pfold = employeeproof.proof_value
  so on...
end
```

Comment: You can simply check for `when 1`

Answer (score 0):

Do it like :

```
case employeeproof.proof.id
when 1
// Do Something here...
break
when 2
// Do Something here...
break
else
// Do Something here...
break
end
```